# iOS Push Notification returning the number 94

Tags: ruby-on-rails, push-notification, rubygems, apple-push-notifications

I'm integrating push notification for iOS using the gem [houston](https://github.com/nomad/houston) on Ruby on Rails as the web service but whenever I try to send a push notification, it only returns the number "94". Tested it a few hours ago, it returned the number "83" instead. What do you think is causing this and what does those numbers mean?

Code:

```
    token = params[:user]["device_token"] 
    certificate = File.read("../flux-ws/public/certificates/#{PEM_FILE}")
    passphrase = ""
    connection = Houston::Connection.new(GATEWAY_URI, certificate, passphrase)

    connection.open

    notification = Houston::Notification.new(device: token)
    notification.alert = {
     :body => "HELLO WORLD"
    }
    notification.badge = 57
    pushed_data = connection.write(notification.message)

    connection.close
```

Return value:

```
    {"pushed_data":94,"status":200}
```

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, guys. I solved it. The bundle id on the pem file didn't match with the bundle id on my project. That was what caused it and after I matched both, it delivered the push notification successfully.